# How to Speed Up Interpreting Speed in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a script in python that takes excel sheet and reads it stores in a tuple, then using selenium web-driver it injects the values in the web form, but i think its a bit slow approach to do so, isn't there any way the whole code executes in an instant without going line by line.

Maybe making a separate async thread for each line?

Here are some of the lines:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//div[@data-id='Year']//select/option[text()='" + str(int(year)) + "']").click()
            self.small_wait()

            self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//div[@data-id='Make']//select/option[text()='" + str(make) + "']").click()
            #self.medium_wait()
            if re.search(r'(?<=\s\d)[-](?=\d)', str(model)) != None:
                rgx = re.compile(r'(?<=\d)[-](?=\d)')
                model = str(rgx.sub('.', str(model)))
            self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//div[@data-id='Model']//select/option[text()='" + str(model) + "']").click()
            #self.small_wait()

            self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//div[@data-id='PrimaryUse']//select/option[text()='Commute To/From Work']").click()
            #self.small_wait()
            self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='bq_add_clone_Vehicle_1'][@value='No']").click()
            #self.small_wait()

            self.browser.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//div[@data-id='CoverageType']//select/option[text()='Standard Protection']").click()
```

All in one any way to optimise or speed the process up? it takes an average of 15 seconds to process one form it has like 10 fields , nothing fancy.

Thanks

Comment: step 1: try to find how the form is processed, usually its a post request to some action url.
step 2: look at the post data, how it is structured, try to structure your data similarly and send the post request at that action url.

you can use requests library to send this request. As selenium is quite slow, requests should help you process things in few seconds.

Comment: But i also want to visualize what's happening.

Comment: You asked for it to go "in an instant"... how do you hope to meet that goal and also "visualize what's happening?" Sounds like you need to spend some time thinking about what you actually want and then come back and update your question with what you've decided. People are spending time trying to answer your question and you are rejecting what seem to be valid answers (you are wasting people's time).

Comment: Thanks Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out which POST request is made when you submit the form. Then send a POST request directly without using selenium. It will dramatically improve your script performance.

Comment: Thanks mate! Appreciated!